# Meshcat takes time to load simple geometries

Tags: drake

This might be a very silly thing but whenever I run the meshcat visualizer it takes quite a bit of time (~ 1-2 mins) to load up simple geometries like a robot and a block, before actually demonstrating the visualization. Often, if the main python script execution finishes, I don't see the final trajectory visualisation as the meshcat server is no longer up. I have put various sleeps and user inputs to make the script persist, but I was wondering if there was anything I should be aware of in the browser settings/meshcat params that I may not be doing optimally.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to use [`meldis`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.visualization.html). Its primary benefit in this regard is that you can run your simulation once (albeit for a brief time), get all of the loading done, and then if you run the simulation again, `meldis` persists its state and get down to running the simulation state.

To do this:

1. Make sure you configure visualization using some variant of [`AddDefaultVisualization()`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1visualization.html#a02befd8c90155c339a042f2af39d4c12) or [`ApplyVisualizationConfig`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1visualization.html#acfe50d1cfd6c229aab5986a0a3c97494). This will configure Drake to dispatch LCM messages.
2. Launch `meldis` in an external process. [This documentation](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/visualization/meldis.py#L1-L26) provides several alternate means of doing so.

Then it's a case of running your simulation enough to load the geometry, killing it, and then restarting it.

Comment: Ooh nice, I was assuming that meldis was mostly there to interface the traditional drake-visualizer with meshcat. I'll try this out and report. Is there anyway to make meshcat itself load the geometries faster?

Comment: Making meshcat faster will be a longer task -- basically, it requires changes that will allow the browser to cache those assets. That will help (reducing the redundant communication overhead). At that point, it becomes a question of how fast three.js loads things. If you want to find out how fast it can be, export a static html of your scene and see how fast that page starts up. It'll tell you how fast the geometry gets loaded.

Comment: Hi, I have been running into these same issues even when trying to run some of the manipulation [notebooks](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/87d8044f-3eb2-4f25-b52f-f51a5eca68b7/notebook/point_finger-c961c7f9eeef4aabb2eda47833464013) locally. Is there anything I can do to make it faster? I dont see how meldis can work here given that I am trying to visualise this from the jupyter notebook.

Comment: You can specify the meshcat url in your jupyter notebook (rather than the default) and simply have the meldis running externally. I believe. This may be wrong, I'm not particularly notebook savvy.